# GridView translate animation

Tags: android, animation, gridview, grid-layout, android-gridlayout

I want to animate my gridview cells in the same way like in the [2048 game](http://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/)

I couldn't find any examples of anything similar and I have no experience in Android animation (or any animation to be correct)

I've looked at [GridLayoutAnimationController](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/GridLayoutAnimationController.html) but didn't get how to implement exactly what I need.

Can someone shed some light over this for me?

Comment: Are you found any solution for this?

Comment: Not really. I believe that its just not meant to have this behavior. You're better of using some custom drawables and animation

Comment: Yeah i do it by `Canvas` and `RectF`.but i couldn't find any solutions to translate animation.